# IIS forgets virtual directory permissions - An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I have a website with a virtual directory that contains PDFs.
Users access the PDFs by using a URL such as http://myApp.com/PDFs/12345678.pdf, where `PDFs` is a virtual directory mapped to `\\\actualPhysicalServerName\PDFsDirectory\`.
This works.

I routinely re-deploy the application. Once the application is redeployed and the website restarted, users can no longer access the virtual directory until IIS is restarted.

Accessing the above URL gives the following error:

> An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to `\\\actualPhysicalServerName\PDFsDirectory\web.config` because access is denied.
>
> ```
> at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.FindDirectoryMonitor(String dir, Boolean addIfNotFound, Boolean throwOnError)
> at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.StartMonitoringFile(String alias, FileChangeEventHandler callback)
> at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.StartMonitoringStreamForChanges(String streamName, StreamChangeCallback callback)
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.MonitorStream(String configKey, String configSource, String streamname)
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
> ```

Restarting the application pool does not help.
I have to restart IIS.
Once IIS is restarted, the virtual directory can be accessed as expected.

Is this expected behavior? Have I set up my virtual directories incorrectly?

I am using IIS 7.5, Windows 7 server, and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 19):

I solved this problem this way:

1. Created new pool with "**No managed code**" and "**Classic**" settings.
2. Converted virtual directory to application, connecting with a user account with permissions on the share
3. Have application use the new pool

Comment: For me works if delete web.config line: `<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\adminapp" `

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else frustrated with the same issue -  while I did not find the crux of the problem, I did figure out that this problem was related to the **Identity** of the **Application Pool** that the website was running under.

In my case, the solution was to change the **App Pool** identity from the **ApplicationPoolIdentity Built-in account** to a custom account that is an administrator on all of the machines involved.

To do this

- Right click on the **application pool in IIS**,  Choose **Advanced Properties**.
- Under **ProcessModel**->**Identity** , choose **Identity**. Choose **Custom Account** (Built-in account, Application Pool Identity is the default in **IIS 7.5**)
- Switch to using a **Custom Domain** account, that is an administrator on this machine, as well as the machine where the virtual directory is hosted.

  - Restart the **Application Pool**.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Virtual directory pointing to images on UNC share. All was working fine until we updated parent app to .NET 4.5.

We had to convert the VirDir to Virtual Application with 4.0 Integrated Application Pool.

Comment: I was wondering why this "stopped" working, until I saw the key "updated parent app to .NET 4.5".

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but I was able to solve it by following these [instructions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b903b64d-c505-4180-8461-c9627a95768a/i-am-getting-the-message-an-error-occurred-loading-a-configuration-file-directory?forum=wcf) (basically add ASPNET and IUSR to permissions:

1. In Windows Explorer, browse to the application folder or to the virtual directory that contains the content (for example, c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xx).
2. Right-click the folder, and then click Properties.
3. On the Security tab, click Add.
4. On the "Select Users or Groups" window, click on Advance
5. Click on Find Now button, you will see List of users
6. Select ASPNET and IUSR_(machinename) then click OK to close the"Select Users or Groups" window
7. Allow the following permissions for the ASPNET and IUSR_(machinename) account:

   -Read & Execute
   -List Folder Content
   -Read

Answer (score 0):

I have just managed to resolve this myself by granting read permissions to IIS_ISURS on my website directory.

I tried to change the App Pool user as per dedgod's answer, but I'm using a corporate machine and couldn't get my network account to work correctly. Hoping this might be of use to anyone using a work machine...

- Right click your website directory in Windows Explorer and select Give Access To > Specific People.
- A new window will pop up - select Find People from the dropdown, then click Locations... and choose your local machine (should be at the top) in the pop-up window.
- Then click Advanced..., which will open yet another pop-up window. Click Find Now and the bottom pane of the window should populate with all of the users for your machine. Find IIS_IUSRS and select it, then click OK to dismiss the window.
- Click OK on the remaining window and this should populate the IIS_IUSRS user in the Network Access list. Assign this user Read permissions and click Share.

IIS should then be able to access your site files.